# Getting Fetch Failed error in NextJS application, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need your help, I'm getting an error message when running my NextJS application, even though my previous application was running fine.

This is the error message I got:

[image: Error message]

This is the message I got from the console:

[image]

My localhost shows error status *"500 Internal Server Error"*:

[image]

This is my code on my index file,

```
import LayoutPage from "@/components/LayoutPage";
import List from "@/components/List";
import Fetch from "@/data/fetching";
import Slide from "@/components/Splide";
import Head from "next/head";

const index = ({
  getTrendingMovies,
  getUpcomingMovies,
  getNowPlayingMovies,
  getPopularMovies,
}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
      </Head>
      <LayoutPage>
        <section className="w-full">
          <Slide data={getTrendingMovies.results} height={500} poster={true} />
          <List data={getUpcomingMovies} title="Upcoming Movies" />
          <List data={getNowPlayingMovies} title="Now Playing Movies" />
          <List data={getPopularMovies} title="Popular Movies" />
        </section>
      </LayoutPage>
    </>
  );
};

export default index;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const getTrendingMovies = await Fetch.getTrending();
  const getUpcomingMovies = await Fetch.getUpcoming();
  const getNowPlayingMovies = await Fetch.getNowPlaying();
  const getPopularMovies = await Fetch.getPopular();
  const getPopularActor = await Fetch.getPopular("person");
  return {
    props: {
      getTrendingMovies,
      getUpcomingMovies,
      getNowPlayingMovies,
      getPopularMovies,
      getPopularActor,
    },
  };
}
```

This is my code on my Fetch.js file,

```
class Fetch {
    static getTrending = async (media = 'movie', time = 'day') => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/trending/${media}/${time}?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = media
        })
        return responseJson
    }

    static getRecommendation = async (media, id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/movie/${id}/recommendations?api_key=${apiKey}&page=1`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = media
        })
        return responseJson
     }

    static getUpcoming = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/movie/upcoming?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = 'movie'
        })
        return responseJson.results
    }

    static getNowPlaying = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/movie/now_playing?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = 'movie'
        })
        return responseJson.results
    }

    static getPopular = async (media = 'movie') => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/popular?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = media
        })
        return responseJson.results
    }

    static getSimilar = async (media, id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/${id}/similar?api_key=${apiKey}&page=1`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        responseJson.results.map(data => {
            data.media = media
        })
        return responseJson
    }

    static getImages = async (media = 'movie', id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/${id}/images?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        // console.log(responseJson.backdrops.slice(0, 10))
        return responseJson
    }

    static getDetail = async (media = 'movie', id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/${id}?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        // console.log(responseJson)
        return responseJson
    }

    static getVideos = async (media = 'movie', id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/${id}/videos?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        // console.log(responseJson.results.filter(video => video.type === 'Teaser' || video.type === 'Clip' ))
        return responseJson.results.filter(video => video.type === 'Teaser' || video.type === 'Clip')
    }

    static getCredits = async (media = 'movie', id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/${media}/${id}/credits?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        return responseJson
    }

    static getCombineCreditsPerson = async (id) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${hostname}/person/${id}/combined_credits?api_key=${apiKey}`)
        const responseJson = await response.json()
        // console.log(responseJson)
        return responseJson.cast
    }
}

export default Fetch
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Please add code in code blocks, not as images.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post :D.

Comment: Please include the console logs. Also if you go to the network tab in chrome and find the failing request and click copy as fetch and add that to the post (wow that was a lot of ands xd) then we should be able to help you a lot better. Also posting a screenshot of your file structure would be helpful

Comment: Your fetch is not calling ur api, it seems to be calling localhost:3000 without any path, check your fetch url ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.